# Java Swing group of Jbuttons without raised portion

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I wanted to know how to display a group of JButtons to look like smooth panel without raised portion.

thanks

Comment: SO you want plain text without any indication to the user that it should be pressed? Why?

Comment: One reason to do this is if you're trying to make a button look like a HTML link.

Comment: no, i had a group of buttons very close to each other and i wanted to give a smooth finish look to buttons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
button.setBorder(null);
```

You may want to look at some of the other "setXXX" method that control painting as well.

Comment: can also use button.setBorderPainted(false);

Answer (score 0):

I've often just used standard JLabels and added mouseListeners to make them clickable.  Alternatively, you could get more advanced and create your own ButtonUI class if you want to really fine-grained control over the rendering of the buttons.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the buttons to be in a row, you can put them in a JToolBar and set Rollover to true. This will make flat buttons that, with mouse over, look raised.